# Calculating "pooled and unpooled" standard error

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Data given:

```
Treatment          Y^bar         n                 s 

1                  18.1          9                 3.851

2                  20.9          23                9.854
```

a. Calculate the **unpooled** standard error for the difference of means.

b. Calculate **pooled** standard error for the difference of means.

how to do that? what do they mean by "pooled and unpooled?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you looked in the index of your textbook for "unpooled" or "pooled" or even "difference of means"?

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the difference between pooled and unpooled?

Hint: pooled tests assumes that two populations have equal variances. Use this to calculate standard error.